# django. ошибка "Страница не найдена (404)"

Tags: python, django

## urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp1.views import index
from myapp1.views import about

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('products/', about)
]
```

## settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-3p#f*26st@)h&$4-r6407x6578lp*+myf5#$!8p#@k%rc%q_8i'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

STATIC_URL = '/css/'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp1'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mydjangoproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mydjangoproject.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = 'css/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'css')]


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'`
```

## index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="urf-6">
        <meta name="outhor" content="Magnat">
        <meta name="description" content="Тестовая страница">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
        <title>Главная страница сайт</title>
    </head>
    <body><h1 style="color: #f99100; text-align: center;
        background-color: rgba(14, 241, 78, 0.786);width: 100cqmax;">
        <big>Вас приветствует<br>Rizmarket</big></h1>
        <hr>
        <p style="text-align: center; background-color: #f99100;width: 100cqmax;">
        <em><big>что вы хотите купить у нас есть все что вы хотите</big></em></p>
        <div>
        <button type="button"     
onclick="location.href='templates/about.html'">Продукты</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

я пробовал наверное все но многи посты с этой ошибкой уже не актуяные пожалуста помогите

вот скрин с ошибкой:

[image]

Comment: `<button type="button"     
onclick="location.href='templates/about.html'">Продукты</button>`  у вас ссылка стоит на файл html, а должна быть ссылка из urls.py, подозреваю, что вы хотели указать `products/` вместо `templates/about.html`

Comment: можете подсказать как это сделать

Comment: так я же написал, `products/` вставьте вместо`templates/about.html` в `href`, что бы получилось: `href='products/'`. Ошибка какая то вылазит?

Comment: спасибо большое помогло